# Header background image causing horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

http://www.barrdisplay.com/

Hey everyone - So the site I am working on has a header background that extends off the screen to the right.. My issue is that horizontal scrolling now occurs because of this.

My #Header has a width of 1450px - which is causing this issues.

How can I fix this issue?

Greg

Answer (score 1):

use in your css

```
body{

overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Note:It will be good to have a read and then use

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Answer (score 0):

Header is a div box. If it is set to 1450 then the div is that wide and causing the horizontal scrolling. Set it to something smaller or a percent (like 100% which will go to the end of the page what ever size it may be) and the background will fill it in to that point.

If you need the background to stretch the entire way, then put the header background as a background for the page and tell it to not repeat and place the center of the image in the center of the screen.